# Resuming docker mysql instance after restarting

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm using docker to run a mysql 5.6 instance on my localhost (which is running ubuntu 20.04), [using these instructions](https://www.codementor.io/@arpitbhayani/setup-multiple-mysql-servers-with-different-versions-docker-du107solq).  When I create a new container for the database I use the following command

```
sudo docker run --name mysql-56-container -p 127.0.0.1:3310:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword -d mysql:5.6
```

That serves the intended purpose; I'm able to create the database using port 3310 and get on with what I want to do.

However when I reboot my localhost, I am unable to get back into sql5.6 using that port again.

When I list containers, I see none listed:

```
$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                             PORTS     NAMES
```

So I try to recreate it and am told that it already exists:

```
$ sudo docker run --name mysql-56-container -p 127.0.0.1:3310:3306 -e   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword -d mysql:5.6
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/mysql-56-container" is already in use by container "a05582bff8fc02da37929d2fa2bba2e13c3b9eb488fa03fcffb09348dffd858f". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

So I try starting it but with no luck:

```
$ sudo docker start my-56-container
Error response from daemon: No such container: my-56-container
Error: failed to start containers: my-56-container
```

I clearly am not understanding how this works so my question is, how do I resume work on databases I've created in a docker container after I reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker ps` just list running containers. If you reboot your laptop, all of them will be stopped. You can use `docker ps --all` or `docker container ls --all` to list all containers (running or stopped). You can check more about the docker ps command in [docker ps command line reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/)

Once a container is created, you cannot create another with the same name. Tha is the reason your second `docker run` is failing.

You should use `docker start` instead. But you are trying to start a container with a different name. Your docker start command is using a container named `my-56-container` but it is called `mysql-56-container`. Please check your first docker run command in the question.